# Can anyone explain Ayende's CompositeObservable solution?

Tags: observable

According to "[Ayende's Implementation of Fact](http://ayende.com/blog/4113/conditions-and-facts)", he states that if the condition is based on more than one observable, the solution is a `CompositeObservable`.

Anyone can explain or show me an example of CompositeObservable based on Ayende's definition?